# Why is my Forrest-Tomlin update worse than recomputing LU?

Tags: linear-programming, linear-algebra

I wrote a simple C++ implementation of the revised simplex method that recomputes the LU decomposition of the basis from scratch on each iteration. I have to solve problems with many variables but few constraints (say, 50 constraints and 5000 variables or more), so I thought that was ok.

Then I decided to implement a basis refactorization approach, so I chose the Forrest-Tomlin basis update approach. I observed that the program became much slower! I would like to understand why and whether this is expected for the kinds of problems (few constraints, many variables) that I consider.

A few words on how I have implemented Forrest-Tomlin. Say that the initial basis matrix is factorized as $B = LU$. After $k$ updates, I have a factorization $B = LR_1\cdots R_k U$ (I am for simplicity ignoring the permutation matrices involved). Then to solve the system $Bx = b$ I have to solve $L R_1 \cdots R_k y = b$ and then $Ux = y$. Solving $L R_1 \cdots R_k y = b$ is easy since the matrices $R_i$ are very special; solving a system $R_i x = b$ takes linear time.

What I have observed after profiling is that most of the time was spent solving systems with the $R_i$ matrices. With Forrest-Tomlin there is an added cost to solve a system, and since I have many more columns than rows, to find the incoming variable I have to solve many systems, which becomes less efficient the more updates I make. And this extra cost is much higher than computing the LU decomposition from scratch.

Does this make sense? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Forrest-Tomlin is designed to take advantage of the sparse nature of your problem. Since the extra cost does not scale with the number of variables, but the number of constraints, it is not the cause of the issue. The problem could lie in the design of the implementation.